# Syntax of "not only" + "furthermore"

Tags: synonyms, conjunctions, syntactic-analysis

Can I use *not only* with *furthermore* instead of *also*?

> Not only is he tall, he is also heavy.

Can I say or write:

> Not only is he tall, he is furthermore heavy.

or (and please tell me if this one is correct):

> Not only is he tall, but furthermore he is heavy.

Comment: The usual collocation is *Not only . . . but also. . . .*

Comment: @tchrist What is wrong with, "Not only is he tall, he is also heavy" without any further additions. This would be common in speaking. I'm working on a "not only" sentence right now and need to know if I need some sort of conjunction instead of just a comma.

Answer (score 1):

In the sentences you have given:

- "Not only is he tall, he is furthermore heavy" is incorrect for your context (it appears to imply that he is additionally heavy).
- "Not only is he tall, but furthermore he is heavy" is relatively better than the first one but should be changed to something like "He is tall and furthermore he is heavy" (see http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/furthermore for a similar sentence).

Use *furthermore* in place of *additionally* or *moreover* or *more importantly*.

Though it works reasonably well as a replacement of *also* in cases where it appears at the beginning of a second sentence that provides more information about a preceding sentence, or right after a conjunction such as *and*, it cannot always be used as an in-place replacement for *also*, as given in your first example.

Answer (score 0):

"Not only" must be followed by a "but also" clause:

*Not only is he tall, but he is also heavy*